# How can I move the middle column to the left column?

Tags: html, css, css-float, positioning

http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/zfBPQ/1/

Essentially I want

[ 33% of remaining space | 100px | 67% of remaining place ]

This is as close as I've been able to get so far...

---

I'm trying to *avoid* using JavaScript. Everything's easy with JS... but I really don't want to rely on it just for some positioning. Users aren't guaranteed to have it enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with CSS alone. You need to use JavaScript to calculate remaining space. In the following example, middle div is 100px, left is 33% and right is 67% of remaining space. With Query you can do

```
function calc() {
    var ww = $(window).width();
    var rem = ww - $('.div2').width();
    $('.div1').css('width', rem * 0.33);
    $('.div3').css('width', rem * 0.67);
}
calc();
$(window).resize(calc);
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/HpJXk/

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned I'm trying to avoid JS... you sure this isn't possible without?

Comment: Why? I've gotten all my divs the correct size, I just need some float/absolute positioning magic to get them in the correct place.

Comment: @mark, that's is the problem, you need middle div to be 100px not the left div + 2 other divs nested in another div as you have it in your example. We need to calculate remaining space and then give each part it's required percentage.

Comment: My point is that you don't need to "calculate" anything if you put all the fixed width divs on one side, and then wrap all the %-width divs in a parent div that will fill the remaining space. I was hoping that I could then float the divs outside of this parent div into the correct position. I could probably do so with absolute positioning, or margins, but then fixed width divs need to know the actual width of the %-width divs to set the margins correctly. Maybe.... I've got one more thing I can try. Otherwise, this makes me sad that we can't even position things like this, with CSS3?

Comment: You can use tables if you must do it with HTML/CSS only. You can also look at `display:table` and `display:table-cell` CSS properties on how to make divs act like tables, but this will not work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Hah! Solved it. And you guys said it couldn't be done!

http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/zfBPQ/3/

I had to duplicate the 100px div, but there's no Javascript involved.

Comment: This will break in IE6, and will also break if you resize the window. The solution i gave you is cross browser compatible

Comment: Set a min-width for the container so it doesn't break. If someone is browsing the internet with IE6 they can't expect to get a perfect experience.

Comment: @Dan: On which one? The black one that holds everything? The problem only occurs when 33% is less than 100 pixels I believe.